# cocos2d game scene wrong resolution

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocosbuilder

i'm new to the world of cocos2d, but I come from the java where I've a good experience ..

As an introduction to the world of cocos2d I followed the following tutorial tha i reccomend:

**http://maniacdev.com/2012/10/tutorial-how-to-quickly-create-a-game-using-the-cocosbuilder-cocos2d-editing-tool**

unfortunately I have a problem that I can not overcome in any way ...

I implemented the project following the tutorial , and I have also downloaded the source from GitHub ...

The game starts , the input screen is displayed properly on the simulator ... BUT, the game screen itself instead of appearing as in the tutorial looks like zoomed, bigger than it should be and the parts of the game that are out of the screen of the simulator obviously are not displayed ..... everything is bigger than should be and so many parts of the application cannot be viewed ...

Among i had the exact same problem also testing directly the sources made ​​available on GitHub ....

Could someone direct me???

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Which version of cocos2d? Any version below 2.1 is probably still having the rotation issue, where the scene size initally is set to portrait and thus incorrect for the very first scene.

Comment: cocos2d-iphone-2.1, i dont download the 3.x project cause is not a stable version....And Cocos Builder Version 2.1

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance you're having trouble with retina vs. non-retina displays. You'll want to make sure that you're checking the value of `CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR()` when implementing sizes. If you follow to the definition of that macro (ccMacros.h) you'll find some more macros to help you with handling differing devices.

You'll also want to check that you're sizing things relative to the window size. This can be found in `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize]`.

Other than that, post more code and we'll try help you out.

Comment: Tonight...i will post a image of the game scene..so it maybe can help...and commit on my gitHub....